# for loop in Bash doubling the step value each time

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

Following [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) basic tutorial on bash loops I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# since Bash v4

i=16
max=256

while [  $i -le $max ]; do 
     echo $i
     let i=i*2
done
```

But since I find this horrible (I'm a pure `while` hater), is there any way to write something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# since Bash v4

start = 16
max = 256

for i in {start..max..i*2}
do
     echo $i
done
```

Comment: Please consider using better material than TLDP -- the ABS, in particular, has a reputation as the w3schools of bash, full of bad-practice examples and outdated content. The [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is one such better reference; there are others in the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: BTW, `{start..max..i*2}` falls afoul of [BashPitfalls #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D).

Comment: BTW, your `while` loop's condition could be more readably expressed as `while (( i <= max )); do`, since your script uses a `#!/bin/bash` shebang. Similarly, `let` can be replaced with `i=$(( i * 2 ))` (while being POSIX-compliant), or with the extended syntax `(( i=i*2 ))`.

Comment: Also, `start = 16` and `max = 256` are both buggy -- they're running `start` and `max` as commands (with `=` as the first argument, and a number as the second), not performing assignments. Take out the spaces: `start=16`, and `max=256`. This is something http://shellcheck.net/ will catch for you, btw.

Comment: You can't do shell programming and hate `while`. Learn to _love_ it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your suggestion,  I'll use it in future

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks for your suggestion. Of course I will have to use `while` sometimes (see `while(true)` ), but I will always prefer a `for` whenever possible ;)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The two have different purposes. It's like saying I prefer to use `ls` instead of `mv` whenever possible.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I understand what you mean, but in this context they are the same and `for` is a more readable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for ((i = 16; i <= 256; i = i * 2)); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Gives this output:

```
16
32
64
128
256
```

Comment: Except, perhaps, for quoting the expansion of `$i` as a matter of routine (and to deal with oddball corner cases like digits in `IFS`), this is exactly what I would have written.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: learning a lot from you! I just made the change you suggested.

Comment: FWIW, I would have written `i *= 2`. (Or `i += i`, but that's really a bad habit.)